# scrreprt: treat bibliography as section

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, koma-script, scrreprt

In `scrreprt`, using `scrlayer-scrpage` I have the header set up so it says "Chapter #" in the outer header of the even page and "Chapter title" in the outer header of the odd page. I would like this header to continue in this exact way in the bibliography as well (see image). I figured that this would work if Latex treated the bibliography as a section inside of the current chapter instead of as a chapter by itself. How do I achieve this?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[A5paper, twoside, openright, headsepline, chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark{chapter}
%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

%%%%---bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%%%---blindtext
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title of a chapter}

\lipsum[1-5] 
citing \cite{angenendt, doody, matuz:doody, gillies, herrmann, kastenholz, murray, reese, sarfraz}

\section{Title of a section}

\lipsum[6-10] 
citing \cite{aksin, sigridsson, spiegelberg, springer, weinberg, yoon, augustine, cicero, coleridge, companion}

\printbibliography  

\end{document}
```

Comment: The bibliography should be a section in chapter 1?

Comment: There was a redundant `\automark{chapter}` in [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504712/43317), sorry. I have changed this in the answer there.

Comment: @esdd you've been helping me out a lot lately, thanks! And yes, the bilbiography should indeed be a section inside chapter 1. I'll edit the question

Comment: Then you only have to add `bibliography=leveldown` to the class options. Note that `A5paper` is not a valid option. Replace it by `paper=A5` or `paper=a5` or `a5paper`.  Additionally add `DIV=14` (adjust the value to your needs) because the automatical calculated value (26) is too big.

Comment: @esdd I'll change those things, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your issue. If the bibliography should be a section using document class `scrreprt` and package `biblatex` you can add option `bibliography=leveldown` to the class options.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  a5paper,% <- corrected
  DIV=14,% <- added
  twoside, openright, headsepline, chapterprefix=true,
  bibliography=leveldown% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% <- added to avoid a biblatex warning

%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

%%%%---bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%%%---blindtext
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title of a chapter}

\lipsum[1-5] 
citing \cite{angenendt, doody, matuz:doody, gillies, herrmann, kastenholz, murray, reese, sarfraz}

\section{Title of a section}

\lipsum[6-10] 
citing \cite{aksin, spiegelberg, springer, weinberg, yoon, augustine, cicero, coleridge, companion}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]